# Optimize Laravel Query

Tags: mysql, laravel

please someone can optimize this query according to Laravel query builder with some help of joins

```
Product::select(DB::raw('
            products.*
            ,(select name from users where users.id=products.user_id) as user_name
          '))
                ->where(function ($query) use ($searchKey) {
                    if (trim($searchKey) != '') {
                        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . trim($searchKey) . '%');
                    }
                })
                ->orderBy($orderBy,$orderType)
                ->paginate(10)
```

Comment: Use a join, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
//Start your query as usual, but just join the user data in. Do not use paginate function yet as this will trigger the query to execute.
$productQuery = Product
    ::selectRaw('products.*, users.name as user_name')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', 'products.user_id')
    ->orderBy($orderBy, $orderType);
//Check (for each param) if you want to add where clause
//You dont need to nest the where function, unless you have more filters, and need to group statements together
if(!empty(trim($searchKey))) {
    $productQuery->where('name', 'like', '%' . trim($searchKey) . '%');
}
//Execute query
$products = $productQuery->paginate(10);
```

Note that the query builder only touches the db with specific functions like `chunk`, `get`, `first` or `paginate`(there are more). When building the query, you have full freedom of adding filters/ordering/grouping untill you execute the query.

I hope it helps, please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks, it's work for me with a small modification.  `$productQuery->where('products.name', 'like', '%' . trim($searchKey) . '%'); `

Comment: Nice! Could you mark as answer then please. Then i'm helped too :D